# How to get the values of oracle database parameters from a unix development server?

Tags: sql, oracle, unix, unixodbc, ab-initio

How to get the fallowing details from the unix development server?
The below parameter values should be provided in the .dbc file 
and it should be mapped to the ETL Server .

```
dbms:<br> db_version:<br> 
db_home:
<br> db_name: <br> db_nodes: <br>
case: <br>
generate_dml_with_nulls:<br>
field_type_preference:<br>
treat_blanks_as_null:<br>
oldstyle_emptystring_as_null:<br>
fully_qualify_dml: <br>
dml_with_maximum_length:<br>
interface: <br> direct_parallel:
<br>
```

Please correct me if i am any where wrong in asking this question?
Many Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

`select * from V$PARAMETER;` 
This will result the list of all the database parameters

Answer (score 1):

If you can connect to it (not quite sure about your question), you can find some interesting information using the following query:

> SELECT * FROM v$instance;

Comment: Let me explain the scenario clearly.
Actually i need to use a ETL Tool on my remote desktop.
For this purpose I gave the host as my unix development server.
Now everything is working fine with the ETL Server.
The problem came when I kept a Input Table component.
This component will get the data from the specific table of the database for this I have to provide a .dbc file to this component to connect to oracle.
Now I dont Know how to detect Oracle server on unix development server?
Will it be there on the development Server?
Please Suggest.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I'm not familiar with ETL Tools nor detecting the server (seems silly, but I think you can just use a Query Admin program, put in the IP/Network Name of the Dev Server, and connect to Oracle.)

Have you checked into http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/warehouse/index.html ?

Comment: Anthony thank you very much for the Information.
I spoke with the developers about this.
The answer is we will not have any oracle database on the development server.
But we are provided with an oracle developer server on the same environment where development server is present.
So in order to connect to this oracle server from the development server we need to use the .dbc file.In the .dbc file we need to provide the ip address or name of the oracle server to which we are willing to connect and its encrypted password(This is in sync with the idea you promoted) for login.
Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save parameters in a file, you can do it this way:

```
SET WRAP OFF;
SET TRIMSPOOL ON;
SPOOL memory_parameters.txt;
select * from v$parameter;
SPOOL OFF;
```